# Security - Include files based on user content

Tags: php, security, nginx, include

Every single request is passed to PHP, for security reasons and because I don't want to expose static files to unauthorized people.

I am concerned about the possibility of someone inject some malicious code through the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable. I tried to remove sub-folders references but I still don't know if it's safe.

**Nginx**

```
rewrite ^ /index.php last;
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $uri = strlen ($uri) > 1 ? substr ($uri, 1) : "index.html";
    $uri = preg_replace ("/\/?\.\./", "", $uri, -1); // Remove sub-folders

    if (file_exists (getcwd () . "/" . $uri)) {
        $extension = substr ($uri, strrpos ($uri, "."));

        switch ($extension) {
            case ".css": $mime = "text/css"; break;
            case ".js": $mime = "application/javascript"; break;
            default:
                $info = finfo_open (FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

                $mime = finfo_file ($info, $uri);

                finfo_close ($info);
            break;
        }

        if ($mime === false)
            header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); // Default
        else
            header ("Content-type: " . $mime);

        require ($uri);
    }
    else {
        // Error, blah blah blah
    }
?>
```

Comment: make some ACL, whatever it will be - php array/mysql table/config file/something like .htaccess/anything

Comment: The whole premise of this question just feels wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are concerned about LFI (Local File Inclusion) attacks. It's possible.
Currently when you are checking for . / and \ chars in URI, that would prevent Directory Traversal attack. It's fairly good.
As you guessed, if you include files like this:

index.php?file=something.php
and in index.php
include $_GET['file'];

Attacker could read every file in your server, like this:
index.php?file=../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd

So you have to take measures.
Here is a very good writing from Imperva on how to prevent LFI and RFI (Remote File Inclusion) attacks:
https://www.imperva.com/lg/lgw.asp?pid=463

without registration requirement:
http://www.slideshare.net/Imperva/how-to-prevent-rfi-and-lfi-attacks

Also Here:
http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/2011/20110124.htm

Comment: That’s not really PHP file inclusion as the file’s content is not executed.

Comment: I still got some doubts but you showed me the path of stones, thank you

Comment: @Gumbo, require ($uri); file is executed. Caio, you're welcome, it's not really hard to create a secure web application, but after studying those papers, you'll be able to always write secure PHP files. Have a good luck.